# How to show/hide content based on a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<ul class="ulSPStyle">
    <li><a class="tfSPHT" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPOPT" href="javascript:void(0);">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPAT" href="javascript:void(0);">three</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPPT" href="javascript:void(0);">four</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPCT" href="javascript:void(0);">five</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tfSPHT1 dispArtBody">
    one content
</div>
<div class="tfSPOPT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    two content
</div>
<div class="tfSPAT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    three content
</div>
<div class=" tfSPPT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    four content
</div>
<div class="tfSPCT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    five content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hideContent {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tfSPHT").on("click", "body", function() {
        $(".tfSPHT1").removeClass("hideContent");
    });
    $(".tfSPOPT").on("click", "body", function() {
        $(".tfSPOPT1").removeClass("hideContent");
    });
    $(".tfSPAT").on("click", "body", function() {
        $(".tfSPAT1").removeClass("hideContent");
    });
    $(".tfSPPT").on("click", "body", function() {
        $(".tfSPPT1").removeClass("hideContent");
    });
    $(".tfSPCT").on("click", "body", function() {
        $(".tfSPCT1").removeClass("hideContent");
    });
});
```

How can I modify my JQuery so depending on the link that is clicked, show only the content for the corresponding class with a 1 at the end and make that link the `current` id.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lc14jgoh/2/ I just edited this comment to show the ability to toggle the show/hide

Comment: Something similar except when one content is shown the rest should be hidden and also the clicked link should have the `current` id.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc14jgoh/4/ try this now.

Comment: What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lc14jgoh/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc14jgoh/6/ (I would like the `current` is to be assigned to the link that is clicked and removed from the rest please)

Comment: The above accomplishes that... I added the styles to show you... http://jsfiddle.net/Lc14jgoh/7/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast This is the only solution that is working for me :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the following code:

```
<ul class="ulSPStyle">
    <li><a class="tfSPHT clickMe" data-toggle=".tfSPHT1" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">one</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="tfSPOPT clickMe" data-toggle=".tfSPOPT1" href="javascript:void(0);">two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="tfSPAT clickMe" data-toggle=".tfSPAT1" href="javascript:void(0);">three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="tfSPPT clickMe" data-toggle=".tfSPPT1" href="javascript:void(0);">four</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="tfSPCT clickMe" data-toggle=".tfSPCT1" href="javascript:void(0);">five</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I think the easiest, most universal approach would be to make use of HTML 5's `data-*` attributes which allow you to create custom data tags per each element. You can effectively store any type of data within said tags, which makes it useful if you are loading the information via the backend.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickMe').click(function () {
        $('.clickMe').removeAttr('id');
        $(this).attr('id', 'current');
        $('.dispArtBody').addClass('hideContent');
        var element = $(this).attr("data-toggle");
        $(element).removeClass('hideContent');
    })
});
```

This will allow you to remove the `current` id from the previous link and then set it equal to the link that was recently clicked. It also hides all of the content and then shows the necessary information.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc14jgoh/7/)

Comment: Although everyone was helpful, this was the only one which worked with my existing code flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers work, but there are a lot of pitfalls with the current structure of your HTML.

I prefer using an approach like this.

```
<style>
    .link{
        color:#000;
    }
    .link.current{
        color:#00f;
    }
    .content{
        display:none;
    }
    .content.active{
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<div id="links">
    <a class="link current"href="#">1</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">3</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p class="content active">Content 1</p>
    <p class="content">Content 2</p>
    <p class="content">Content 3</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(".link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".link").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $(".content").removeClass("active");
        $(".content").eq(index).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fjehk7e/1/

Comment: Thank you. Can you please let me know what pitfall I may come across with the way I have it so i have an idea. Thanks.

Comment: This is just my preference. The method I used just relies on the order of the links and the content - the first link corresponds to the first .content, second link to second content, etc.  This saves you from having to give them specific class names in order for it to work. Also I feel that the current status should be a class not an ID

Comment: I see what you did there. I might end up using this. Still testing. Thank you.

Comment: It feels a bit cleaner too, as you aren't fetching class names and then modifying them in order to find the corresponding class for the content. And the HTML is cleaner.

Comment: Agree very clean. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/188kv2xg/2/)

Using a simple function

```
 $('li a').click(function () {
    var cls = $(this).attr('id');

    $('div').hide();
    $('div.' + cls).show();

    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works and it's great. How can I also manage the `current` id? I would like the ID to go to the link that is being clicked on and remove it from the rest.

Comment: I would not suggest changing ids of elements. If you want to keep track of the current link you can use a class. I have updated the function in the post (not the fiddle)

Comment: Thank you. I will work on it. Please update the Fiddle to work with the `current` class for future users. Thanks.

Comment: On a second thought, adding another class can break the logic on second click.But we can switch the roles of id and class. I have updated the fiddle and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a couple of amendments to your jQuery code and clean it up a bit and it should work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // check document has fully loaded
  $('li a').click(function() { // run function when element is clicked
    $('li a').removeAttr('id'); // remove ID from all links
    $(this).attr('id', 'current'); // set id to current for clicked link
    var cls = $(this).attr('class'); // get class of clicked
    $('.dispArtBody').hide(); // hide all other divs
    $('.'+cls+'1').show(); // show div with class of clicked + 1
  });
});
```

```css
.hideContent {
  display: none;
}
a#current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ulSPStyle">
    <li><a class="tfSPHT" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPOPT" href="javascript:void(0);">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPAT" href="javascript:void(0);">three</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPPT" href="javascript:void(0);">four</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPCT" href="javascript:void(0);">five</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tfSPHT1 dispArtBody">
    one content
</div>
<div class="tfSPOPT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    two content
</div>
<div class="tfSPAT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    three content
</div>
<div class=" tfSPPT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    four content
</div>
<div class="tfSPCT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    five content
</div>
```

As suggested by BuddhistBeast, you should really set the link class's to be the ID's instead. and then amend the jQuery to follow that.

Example:

```
<li><a id="tfSPHT" class="current" href="javascript:void(0);">one</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you. +1. How can I add the `current` ID to the link that is clicked and remove it from the rest

Comment: Just be weary that by adding another  class to any of those `li` tags will break this jQuery code.

Comment: If i wanted to add the `current` as a class rather than ID how can I modify the code? I think it is safer to use it as a class.

Comment: I have a class for the `current` which doesn't load when I use this code :/ *SIGH*

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ulSPStyle > li > a").on('click', function(){
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log( className );
        // Updated (with feedback from @BuddhistBeast -thanks)
        $('.dispArtBody').addClass('hideContent');

        $("." + className + "1" ).removeClass( "hideContent" );
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ayc93zt/)**

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer but I did +1 because it also works.

Comment: thanks for the feedback... You may want to have a look at jquery's  `.toggle()` as it seems to do what you want... http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: This seems to be over complicating things... I took out your `$.each` loop to show you that that step was unnecessary: https://jsfiddle.net/5ayc93zt/1/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast You are correct! I did not notice the common class (was only looking at the other one)... thanks

Comment: No worries! I just thought i would highlight that, your answer is correct nonetheless.

Comment: Some helpful people here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you using the code from @aSharma answer, to manage ID you need to add:

```
 $(this).closest("ul").find("a").attr("id", "").end().end().attr("id", "current");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".ulSPStyle li a").on("click", function(e) {
  $("[class^=" + e.target.className + 1 + "]")
  .removeClass("hideContent")
  .siblings("div[class^=tf]")
  .addClass("hideContent")
});
```

```js
$(".ulSPStyle li a").on("click", function(e) {
  $("[class^=" + e.target.className + 1 + "]")
  .removeClass("hideContent")
  .siblings("div[class^=tf]")
  .addClass("hideContent")
});
```

```css
.hideContent {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="ulSPStyle">
    <li><a class="tfSPHT" id="current" href="javascript:void(0);">one</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPOPT" href="javascript:void(0);">two</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPAT" href="javascript:void(0);">three</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPPT" href="javascript:void(0);">four</a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPCT" href="javascript:void(0);">five</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tfSPHT1 dispArtBody">
    one content
</div>
<div class="tfSPOPT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    two content
</div>
<div class="tfSPAT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    three content
</div>
<div class=" tfSPPT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    four content
</div>
<div class="tfSPCT1 dispArtBody hideContent">
    five content
</div>
```